# CSS Not Selector

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use a `:not()` CSS selector, and I've tried multiple combinations of this and nothing is working.

My code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/cLevkr4e/2/

I would like it to be that when I hover over an href in `#steps`, it doesn't highlight the rest of the containing `<li>`.

I would also like it that when I hover over an `<li>` in `#steps`, it applies the hover color change to everything, including the anchor tags.

So when hovering over `.wa a` it should just underline that.

When hovering over the `<li>` it should just change the color of everything including the anchors to `rgb(66, 81, 95)`.

My CSS:

```
 .wa a{
color: rgb(68, 118, 67);
}

.steps {
width:400px;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:left;
line-height: 200%;
}

.steps a:hover {
text-decoration: underline;
}

.steps li:not(a):hover{
cursor: pointer;
color: rgb(66, 81, 95);
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="steps">
<ul>
<li>Apply an Email To Your Nation</li>
<li>Apply To the <span class="wa"><a href="http://www.nationstates.net/page=un">World Assembly</a></span> With That Email</li>
<li>Join the <span class="wa"><a href="http://www.nationstates.net/page=un">World Assembly</a></span></li>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cLevkr4e/5/

Comment: The sentence “it doesn't highlight the rest of the containing `<li>`” is obscure. Of course it doesn't, unless you write code that does such things. You have code that underlines links on mouseover; there is no reason why that would do anything else than that, like “highlight” other content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector (`li:not(a):hover`) says: *When the user overs over a list item that is not an anchor*. An `<li>` will never be a `<a>`.

> I would like it to be that when I hover over an href in #steps, it doesn't highlight the rest of the containing `<li>`.
>
> When hovering over the `<li>` it should just change the color of everything including the anchors to `rgb(66, 81, 95)`.

The problem here is that you cannot point the mouse at the link without also pointing it at the list item that the link is inside.

[CSS 4 proposes `:has()`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#relational) which would allow:

```
li:hover {
    color: rgb(66, 81, 95)l
}

li:hover:has(a:hover) {
    color: black;
}
```

… but nothing currently supports that so what you are looking for is impossible in CSS at present. You could use JavaScript to add and remove classes from the list item when the anchor is hovered though.

Comment: Ah alright, I was hoping to accomplish this w/o JavaScript/Jquery, but I guess I will have to use `.hover()`.

Interesting about CSS 4 though, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This `li:not(a)` makes no sense. Element cannot have `li` and `a' tags at the same time.

What you need here is a hypothetical :has() selector but [it does not exist yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector). Only with it it would be possible to achieve what you want:

```
li:hover { color:red; }
li:hover a { color:inherit; }
li:has(a:hover) { color:black; }
```