# Modifying An Element Already Activated By Another Selector

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I have a bit of a complicated problem.

There are two elements here:

**(1).** When selecting the `$(".steps li")` I want the whole `<li>` to change color to `rgb(66, 81, 95)`. Then it has to change back to how it was before.

This part I have accomplished already, using `.data()`.

The second part is the tricky part:

**(2).** When selecting an `<a>` in the very same `<li>` I want the color to stay the same and the underline to be applied. So I want the "World Assembly" text to stay green, be underlined, and have the rest of the `<li>` be the white, inactivated color.

Is there a way to do this using callbacks in the hover function?

I need (1) and (2) to work at the same time.

I tired to hover on just the $(".steps li a") but that doesn't work because for the first part to work, the class has to be removed.

Anyway, I am unsure about this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Code is below:

CSS:

```
    html, body {
    background: #000;
    color: #e7e7e7;
    font-family:"Helvetica", "Arial", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Verdana", sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
a {
    color: rgb(66, 81, 95);
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    /*color:#a0a0a0;*/
    text-decoration:none;
}
.wa a {
    color: rgb(68, 118, 67);
}
.steps {
    width:400px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:left;
    line-height: 200%;
}
.steps a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.steps li:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgb(66, 81, 95);
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(".steps li").hover(function () {
    var the_class = $(this).children().attr("class");
    $(this).data('class', the_class);
    console.log(the_class);
    $(this).children().toggleClass(the_class);
}, function () {
    $(this).children().attr("class", $(this).data('class'));
});
```

Edit: I actually had to solve this using `$.data()` twice, because in my locally hosted code I ended up having to add more anchor tags in the list, all with their own colors.

It now works like this:

```
 $(".steps li").hover(function () {
    var the_class = $(this).children().attr("class");
    $(this).data('class', the_class);
    $(this).children().toggleClass(the_class);
}, function () {
  $(this).children().attr("class", $(this).data('class'));
});

$(".steps li a").hover(function(){
     $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('notHover');
     $(this).parent().attr("class", $(this).parent().parent().data('class'));
     }, function()
     {
     $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass('notHover');
     $(this).parent().removeClass($(this).parent().parent().data('class'));
     });
```

Comment: When you 'selecting' do you mean 'hovering'?

Comment: this is all very trivial just using css alone. Why do you need script to do it?

Comment: @charlietfl 

Actually it is not. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139375/css-not-selector

Comment: is this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/qa76ek61/3/

Comment: @charlietfl no, see below

Comment: showing expected results would save a lot of guessing. code it iinline

Comment: @charlietfl maybe CSS 4 but I don't think in CSS 3 because I am trying to get the rest of the `<li>` to change back to white when the `<a>` is expressly hovered.

Comment: ok, then a simple toggle class on parent when `<a>` hover would help then. Not on `<li>` hover. Next time if you follow 'how to ask questions` providing an expected result will save lots of time and misunderstandings

Comment: @charlietfl It can't be done in CSS. Selectors Level 4 will add a previous ancestor selector `:has()`, but it won't be available in CSS, only via the DOM. So this isn't possible with just CSS unfortunately, and it won't be, unless browsers include `:has()` functionality w/ CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just toggle a class on the parent `<li>` when `<a>` is hovered.

Then a  new set of rules can cover the li and a colors based on the class

```
$(".steps li a").hover(function){
     $(this).parent().toggleClass('aHovered');
});

.steps li.aHovered{
  color : white
}

.steps li.aHovered a{
  color : green
}
```

Comment: this wasn't working until I added `!important` to the CSS class `aHovered`

:P

Thank you!

Comment: yeah may have to back out some other rules but the basics are there, or make these rules more specific

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple solutions to your problem (I used some hex values, because RGB is typically not used for the web).

**Solution 1: Add/Remove a class on hover**: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qa76ek61/10/)

jQuery:

```
$(".steps li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("color");
});
```

CSS:

```
.color {
    color: #e7e7e7 !important;
}
```

**Solution 2a: Alter your jQuery**: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qa76ek61/13/)

jQuery:

```
$(".steps li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().css("color", "#e7e7e7");
});
$(".steps li a, .steps li").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent().css("color", "");
});
```

CSS:

```
.steps li:hover, .steps li:hover a {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgb(66, 81, 95);
}

.steps li a:hover {
    color: #447643;
}
```

**Solution 2b: Alter your jQuery again**: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qa76ek61/12/)

jQuery:

```
$(".steps li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().attr("style", "color: #e7e7e7");
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().attr("style", "");
});
```

CSS:

```
.steps li:hover, .steps li:hover a {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: rgb(66, 81, 95);
}

.steps li a:hover {
    color: #447643;
}
```

Comment: that is very close and almost acceptable at this point, the problem is in your example, when I hover over the "Word Assembly" text, the rest of the <li> changes color too. That's what I don't want, ideally speaking.

Comment: @LSD You want the non `<a>` link to go back to white when the `<a>` is hovered?

Comment: yes, if the other part of the `<li>` (the non `<a>` part) gets hovered, then change the color of the whole thing, as you have done. but if the  `<a>` part gets selected, have the rest of the `<li>`  revert to white

Comment: @LSD Updated my post. It should do what you ask now. You won't need the `!important` hack with this solution.

Comment: @TylerH would need to back out the inline css on mouseleave

Comment: @charlietfl Damn, you're right. jQuery is complicated.

Comment: can use `removeAttr('style')`

Comment: @LSD Updated my answer again. I would recommend you use Solution 2a or 2b, as Solution 1 (basically the same as what charlietfl provided) requires an `!important` CSS hack to work.

Comment: @TylerH I actually had to go back and use `$.data()` for this because I had multiple anchor tags in the list all with different colors, so neither answer ended up working for me. Using `$.data()` worked though.

Comment: @LSD Ah, I see. In the future, it's best if you can include a *complete* reproduction of the relevant code for your problem. :-) Glad you got it working!